# Most efficient way of dialog branching in MonoGame

Tags: c#, refactoring, monogame

I'm making a text heavy game and I need to know the most efficient way of progressing through dialog branches. Currently I am using a switch to determine what the next line of dialog will be, like this.

```
  if (branch == "A")
            {
                switch (dialogNum)
                {
                    case 0:
                        speaker = "person A"; newDialog = "This is a test.";
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        speaker = playerName; newDialog = "text";
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        speaker = "Person B"; newDialog = "This is a test of";
```

I'm afraid that after it gets lengthy it may slow down the game. I know I could probably have the dialog in something like a text file and load it into a list but I don't think that would necessarily be faster.

So my question is, what's the best way to write dialog for a game without making it slow down.

Comment: why are you using a switch?  Why aren't you just queuing things in a list?

Comment: I'm just concept testing at the moment, I just needed some text in a sequence to draw to the screen. As I said in my question, I know I could use a list but I don't know if that's the best way of doing something like this either.

Comment: Dialog mechanism should never be hard coded into a system.  Imagine you needed to change some text somewhere it would be way inconvenient and not practical.  Basically, have a list with the dialog, create a sequence number in which i needs to be played, and who said it.   Then just iterate over the list and play it in order.  You can store the Text in a db, or just load it from a formatted text file

Comment: Similar to what @johnny5 said, but I would advise to use a tree instead of a list. That should make it easier to progress with different scenarios/reactions.

Comment: @NahuelIanni yeah you're right a tree is definetly better if the player has options on how the dialogue can go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are branching, with switches, should be fast and efficient for a large number of responses. You're probably going to hit and issue with maintainability before you hit an issue with performance. If you are still worried about it, consider dropping things into an array or dictionary. something like `var newDialog = dialogs[dialogNum];` should be faster because you're direct mapping to the answer instead of doing a series of `if (dialogNumber == n)` checks.

That being said, I'd warn you a bit on concerning yourself with performance until it is a real problem for you. If you optimize early you may be solving a problem you'd never have and waste a bunch of time doing it. If you optimize later when you do have a problem you'll spend about the same time doing the optimization, but now you'll have a much better understanding of what your code needs to do and you'll be able to easily observe whether or not your optimizations have done anything. It may be hard to resist the urge, but if you can manage you'll profit in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Even in a very *dialogue-heavy* game `switch` won't probably be a problem in run-time. But it would get tedious to edit it.

If you'd like, you can can keep your dialogues in some text format in files (for a live example, you may download [Ren'Py](https://www.renpy.org/) (a visual novel engine in python. Disclaimer: I don't use it myself, but it's a good example of how to store dialogues). Or to use some inprocess database like [SQLite](https://sqlite.org/). That way you can load your dialogues from the disk when the game needs them and then add them to some collection - for example, `Dictionary<String,String>`. Access speed won't matter. Even a heavy slow collection would allow millions of accesses/second, so the speed is probably of no concern. You may also consider using some advanced structuring, like using `Dictionary<YourStructThatWorksLikeATag,YourClassThatDescribesThePhraseAndHowToPresentIt>` =)